# string manipulation uppercase and lowercase in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-matching

I was asked this question in a recent interview. 
A string contains a-z, A-Z and spaces. Sort the string so that all lower cases are at the beginning, spaces in the middle and upper cases at the end. Original order among lower and upper cases needs to remain the same. This is what I came up with:

```
$str = "wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA";

$lowercase ="";
$uppercase="";
$spaces="";

for ($i=0 ; $i <= strlen($str)-1 ; $i++)
{
    if ($str[$i] <= 'z' && $str[$i] >= 'a'  )
    {
        $lowercase .=$str[$i];
    }

    else if (($str[$i] <= 'Z' && $str[$i] >= 'A'))
    {
        $uppercase .=$str[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $spaces.=$str[$i];
    }
}
echo $lowercase.$spaces.$uppercase;

input: wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA
output: wlomtoairi ECECLFONA
```

I'm wondering if there are better ways to do this? And there are 2 spaces in the input string, and the output shows only one space. The complexity of this is O(N) right.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you look at html output the spaces are optimized. Look at html source code to see all spaces.

Comment: interesting, I don't know why html is optimizing the spaces. I'm printing the output string, and if the string has spaces within it, it should display correctly right?

Comment: Therefore you should use: `echo "<pre>".$lowercase.$spaces.$uppercase."</pre>";`

Comment: Yes, edited the original post

Comment: What do mean with `O(N) right`?

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm. O(n) means it is directly proportional to the number of characters in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. You could do it with regular expressions..

```
$str = "wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA";
preg_match_all('~([a-z])~', $str, $lowercase);
preg_match_all('~([A-Z])~', $str, $uppercase);
preg_match_all('~(\h)~', $str, $spaces);
echo implode('', $lowercase[1]) . implode('', $spaces[1]) . implode('', $uppercase[1]);
```

Output:

```
wlomtoairi  ECECLFONA
```

When you say `better` are you referring to performance, readability, or something else?

Second regex approach:

```
$str = "wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA";
echo preg_replace('~[^a-z]~', '', $str) . preg_replace('~[^\h]~', '', $str) . preg_replace('~[^A-Z]~', '', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm looking for a better performance. Can we optimize it. ? Currently it is O(n)

Comment: Regex takes `0.00049` seconds to run, loop takes `0.000143` seconds to run. https://eval.in/417178

Comment: Hmm running benchmarks on eval is bringing back different times, every time. preg_replace is coming back faster though.

Comment: Appreciate your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is pretty OK, but if you are into micro-optimization you could make some minor changes. The following is faster than the regular expression solutions above (benchmark run 10000 times) at least on my system:

```
$str = "wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA";
$lowercase = "";
$uppercase = "";
$spaces    = "";

$end = strlen($str); // Calculate length just once
for ($i = 0; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $c = $str[$i]; // Get $str[$i] once

    // We know there are only A-Z, a-z and space chars so we
    // only need a greater-than check ('a' > 'A' > ' ')
    if ($c >= 'a') {
        $lowercase .= $c;
    } else if ($c >= 'A') {
        $uppercase .= $c;
    } else
        $spaces .= $c;
}
echo $lowercase . $spaces . $uppercase, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimization :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortString($string)
{
    $string_chars = str_split($string);

    $output = ['', '', ''];

    foreach ($string_chars as $char) {
       $output[$char === ' ' ? 1 : ($char === ucfirst($char) ? 2 : 0)] .= $char;
    }

    return implode('', $output);
}

echo sortString("wElComE to CaLiFOrNiA");
```

Gives `wlomtoairi  ECECLFONA`